# After update from F23 to Fedora 24: Can not login to smb share

Tags: fedora, upgrade, samba, smb, shared-folders

When i try to connect to a Windows share with Nautilus in F24, the login credentials screen keeps popping up repeatedly but i don't get access to the shared folder. I recently tried this from F23 live and it worked like a charm. It also works with my Windows 10. Any ideas how i could start hunting this down? There appear to be no similar issues in the bugzilla database so i have to assume this is not a general F24 issue.

**Edit**:

So today i tried tapping into the share via terminal:

```
/usr/bin/smbclient -L moviebox
Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Has something changed from F23 to F24 that would necessitate me adapting settings on the NAS or client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the switch from F23 to F24 there were some updates to smb it seems. Adding `client use spnego = no` to the global section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` on the client fixed this issue.

Comment: Is this option also available through `mount.cifs`? So I don't have to set it in `[global]`?!